# Scrollbar on the right side after the full screen YouTube video of the older version of chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, youtube

If you use an older version (< = chrome72) to access youtube, a scroll bar (at the far right of the screen) will appear after the full screen

[image]

I think of a way to solve this problem, which is to inject the following JavaScript script into the web page

```
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.innerHTML="ytd-app { overflow: overlay  !important; }";
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

After injecting JavaScript script, this problem can be solved, but I always feel that the time of full screen becomes longer (the time from clicking the full screen button to full screen, but I have no conclusive evidence)

I would like to ask two questions

1. Is there a more scientific way to solve the problem (without replacing or upgrading the browser)
2. In terms of the above code, is there any conclusive evidence that it will make the full screen time longer

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an old post and I don't know if I am late or not but I just came across the best solution to this. Add an extension called Improve YouTube from the link that I've attached  [Improve YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improve-youtube-video-you/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd/related?hl=en)

And after that just open youtube on a pew page, click the plugin, go to appearance, click player and then scroll down completely to "Hide <>" and turn it on. This way the scroll bar will be completely gone and you can even scroll down to the comments if you ever feel like it without the the scroll bar being present.

Have a great day :)

Comment: the option is Hide scroll details, my bad it got censored in this